# $GL_k(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{p^k}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I would appreciate some insight. The difficult part for me is proving that the homomorphism $\Phi$ is surjective.

> Consider the group action of $GL_k(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ acting on $\mathbb{(Z_p)^k}$ by matrix multiplication, which induces the homomorphism $\Phi: GL_k(\mathbb{Z_p})\to S_{p^k}$ (since ord$[(\mathbb{Z}_p)^k]=p^k$). This action is faithful and thus $\Phi$ is injective.

Now the final step is to prove that $\Phi$ is surjective, which can be done by arguing that ord$[GL_k(\mathbb{Z_p})]=p^k!$. Or is there a better way?

> Resolved: $GL_k(\mathbb{Z}_p)\cong H$, where $H < S_{p^k}$ by virtue of the First Isomorphism Theorem: $GL_k(\mathbb{Z}_p)/\{e\} \cong im(\Phi)$.

Comment: The First Isomorphism Theorem is massive overkill here: since $\Phi$ is injective, it is a bijection onto its image, so it is an isomorphism from $GL_k(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ to its image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not surjective.  If it were surjective, that would mean that every bijection $\mathbb{Z}_p^k\to\mathbb{Z}_p^k$ is a linear map, which is certainly false (as long as $k>0$).  This shows that $|GL_k(\mathbb{Z}_p)|<p^k!$, so $GL_k(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ cannot be isomorphic to $S_{p^k}$ by any other map either.

However, it is of course surjective when considered as a map to its image, so it gives an isomorphism from $GL_k(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ to the subgroup $\operatorname{im}(\Phi)$ of $S_{p^k}$.

Comment: +1. Indeed, $|GL_{k}(\mathbb{Z}_{p})| = \prod_{j=1}^{k} p^{k}-p^{j-1}$, which is clearly less than $p^{k}!$. But this argument is the best way to see things.

Comment: Thanks, I made the correction.